# Is every nonempty open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Is every nonempty open set $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

I think this is false; perhaps I can take $U$ to be the disjoint union of two open balls. But how can I prove that this is not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

More generally, do diffeomorphisms preserve connectedness, or number of connected components?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For two sets to be diffeomorphic, they must be homeomorphic. Connectedness (and number of connected compotents) is a topological property and is therefore preserved under homeomorphism. Therefore $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not homeomorphic to any disconnected open subset of itself.

Comment: and if we assume $U$ connected?

Comment: Still not. Take the [annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus)

Comment: @VeridianDynamics The statement _may_ hold if your set is open and convex or perhaps open and star-like.

Comment: @eepperly Contactible, I think, is sufficient.

Comment: @Arthur Unfortunately, no. [There are rather surprising counterexamples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_R4#Small_exotic_R4s). But even better; there are contractible open subsets of $\Bbb R^3$ which are not even homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^3$: [eg, the Whitehead manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_manifold)

Comment: @eepperly16 This is indeed true for open star-like subsets, but is rather hard to prove. See, eg, this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4468/what-are-the-open-subsets-of-mathbbrn-that-are-diffeomorphic-to-mathbb/212595#212595)

Answer (score 6):

Diffeomorphism saves connectedness. But here $\mathbb R^n$ is connected and union of two disjoint open sets is not connected.